# Slow running Ubuntu 10.10 laptop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, performance

I have a slow computer.  When I click on an icon say Firefox it can take 10 seconds to load.  when I minimize and maximize windows you can see it happening.  I get "ghost" screens where you see the window outline of the box but nothing in it or it may be white.

The laptop is two years old and has these specs:

- Intel Core 2 Duo 2.8GHz CPU
- 4GB RAM
- 500GB HDD
- 512MB NVIDIA GeForce 8600GT video card
- Realtek HD audio

What is going on and where should I start looking for issues?  Ubuntu 10.10 was upgraded from 10.04LTS following the instructions from the Ubuntu Wiki and it was done through the update manager GUI, not the CLI.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to add a proprietary driver for your video card

Look under System > Administration > Hardware   to see if any better drivers are available

If not, then try turning off the visual effects.

Answer (score 1):

I found this... worked for me give it a shot.. check out one of the answers

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1626633